# How to display column total in last row of table

Tags: jquery, html

Here i am displaying values in the table. At the last row I need to display the total of column totalamt. `var total;`is the field collecting sum of TotalAmt. I need to display this in the last row.

```
        if (data.length > 0) {

            var tr;

            var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var date = new Date(data[i].CompDt);

                var month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
                var total = 0;


                var sprintno =  data[i].ID;
                var totalamt = data[i].TotalAmt;
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + month + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + no + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + totalamt + "</td>");
                $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
            }

            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                total = total + data[i].TotalAmt;
            }

            tr = $('<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white" />');
            tr.append("<td></td>");
            tr.append("<td></td>");
            tr.append("<td></td>");


            $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example include the previous answer and a fix to your code (`sprintno` in place of `no`):

https://jsfiddle.net/m6hxwhev/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('#GraphTable').append('<tr><td>'+total+'</td></tr>');
```